# How to get current region or current block of node in hook_theme_suggestions_node()

Tags: hooks, 9

I need to get the current region or the current block where a node is rendered, in `hook_theme_suggestions_node()`.

```php
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_node(array $variables) {
  $node_region = "I don't know how to get it";
  $node_block = "I don't know how to get it";
  $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node_region . '__' . $node_block;    
}
```

I need only one value between `$node_region` and `$node_block`. How can I obtain them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a node to display differently on different parts of the page, the way to do that is to use [View modes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752).

Comment: Thank you. Solution is to put teaser node in Entity view (Content) block from Chaos Tools module. After that I have separated two nods on page teaser and full.